# Firebase is not registering for Flutter iOS but successfully reports Crashlytics data

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, analytics

I've set up FlutterFire for my Flutter app, but for some reason, the setup step for iOS seems to be stuck at

```
Checking if the app has communicated with our servers. You may need to uninstall and reinstall your app.
```

In addition, my crash-free statistics chart is not showing any data, so I believe it might have something to do with the setup being incomplete. I have integrated the latest versions of `firebase_analytics` and `firebase_crashlytics` since my `pubspec.yaml` file contains the following:

```
firebase_analytics: "^6.0.0"
firebase_core: "^0.5.0"
firebase_crashlytics: "^0.2.0"
```

The whole process is up and running for Android, but this is only occurring on iOS. I believe I have correctly configured the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file since Crashlytics is successfully sending crash reports to the dashboard. dSYMs are also correctly being uploaded. Is there anything I could be missing?